# TypeScript Logic conundrum - A AND EITHER B or C or D

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, logic, typing

I'm trying to set up a type for a custom input component that will inherit properties based on the type of element to be displayed. Essentially the logic is what the title states

```
type A AND EITHER B or C or D or E
```

meaning A is always applied, then either B or C or D or E follow. Here's what I have so far.

```
 interface GenericInputElementProps {
  id: string;
  hidden: boolean;
  label: string;
  onInput: (
    id: string,
    value: string | number,
    isValid: boolean
  ) => {
    type: string;
    value: string | number;
    inputId: string;
    isValid: boolean;
  };
  validators?: { type: string; configVal?: number }[];
  initialValue?: {
    initialValue: string;
    initialValid: boolean;
  };
}

type InputElementProps =
  | (
      | GenericInputElementProps
      | {
          element: 'input';
          type: string;
          placeholder: string;
          errorText: string;
        }
    )
  | {
      element: 'textarea';
      rows: number;
      placeholder: string;
      errorText: string;
    }
  | { element: 'number'; type: 'number' }
  | { element: 'checkbox'; type: 'checkbox' }
  | { element: 'select'; sizes: ISizes[] };
```

but this doesn't work because typescript thinks I'm using `GenericInputElementProps` and `element='input'` but doesn't consider the other options. I'm sure there is a way around this but I cannot find out what pattern I can use.

Comment: Your parentheses don't actually do anything. `(A | B) | C | D` is simply `A | B | C | D`.

Comment: Also, you don't show us how/where you use it, and the actual error TypeScript emits. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or in other words, the minimal standalone code needed to demonstrate the problem. I should be able to copy your code into for example, the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q) and immediately see the errors.

Comment: A plain reading of "A AND EITHER B or C or D" implies `A & (B | C | D)`, have you tried that?  I agree with previous comments; we need a [mre] that demonstrates the actual issue directly.

Comment: Prettier added the parenthesis, idk why.  I did and it didn't seem to work, typescript has a weird thing with parenthesis where I don't know when/why they matter if at all. 
I ended up just creating a separate type for each possibility that extends the generic prop and in the props argument passed each possibility as OR.
so 
(props: A & B | A & C | A & D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have types `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`, and you want to represent "`A` *and* something which is *either* `B` *or* `C` *or* `D` *or* `E`", then you can do so by turning "and" into an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) and "or" into a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), like:

```
type Okay = A & (B | C | D | E);
// type Okay = A & (B | C | D | E)
```

Those parentheses are important, because intersections bind more tightly than unions in TypeScript syntax:

```
type Oops = A & B | C | D | E;
// type Oops = (A & B) | C | D | E
```

---

That implies you should do something like:

```
type InputElementProps = GenericInputElementProps & (
    {
        element: 'input';
        type: string;
        placeholder: string;
        errorText: string;
    } | {
        element: 'textarea';
        rows: number;
        placeholder: string;
        errorText: string;
    } | {
        element: 'number'; type: 'number'
    } | {
        element: 'checkbox'; type: 'checkbox'
    } | {
        element: 'select'; sizes: ISizes[]
    }
);
```

If you want to break those apart into their own interfaces it's up to you:

```
interface TextElementProps {
    element: 'input';
    type: string;
    placeholder: string;
    errorText: string;
};
interface TextAreaElementProps {
    element: 'textarea';
    rows: number;
    placeholder: string;
    errorText: string;
};
interface NumberElementProps {
    element: 'number';
    type: 'number';
};
interface CheckboxElementProps {
    element: 'checkbox';
    type: 'checkbox';
};
interface SelectElementProps {
    element: 'select';
    sizes: ISizes[];
};

type InputElementProps = GenericInputElementProps & (
    TextElementProps |
    TextAreaElementProps |
    NumberElementProps |
    CheckboxElementProps |
    SelectElementProps
);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEARCYD2SDeBYAUEkUgJbAAuEATgGYLICCOSIAXEgAxIC+BxpFanURIAQswBG7Lr0LEylWvSQBhZvGk8+8wUpEpmAE02z+CocoCizCCYLai5AJ4xkAeQDWIJ0gC8SJgAyJAAKcQAfVSRIg0jLAEoAbgckAHpUpGdXJE9vPwCkYLDoqJiShJSs9wwYKHygsRK1MrjkuSJ0zJdq2vzm1HKSkIbRePt8WXM9ZABxCGBqEngASWAYAFdySwAbdHnyAAUqGrq8dtJjJChyKjIAczb+AAsSQ0N59gkMDF2QYEfiNsQBIINt2NdbsAHikMMBVhtyOwQikzJcIfcADQo4gANxA23WtiuN3uJWA6zAIKoWPOZigADV8a9Pt9fsAUvE-AA+HDYxzdcEkqEA-hEPEEonoqFkilUkWisgI5ZooXQ2nyBlMy5fH4QP7y7jy8WvEDkDBUKAAfnY2C6rkFkIeSHgsJoJDujO21qQ5Mp1B4AG0ALrysgkcgkfGewnes6inThyPbaOS1XyszARNRrUs3X6lKGgiTXTCZDLADKJAAXtBeecAO5PJzsX1UovjUCQWDKNwLADqeTjOkUpaQcwWtxWa02Oz2FCOJzr8aIzOJjvTxBebw+SB1bI3RCBILBa-uB6QsPhmyRfIVKsdNOXovFhIdpMireoj6fGs9q73ersuqRCcr4PJDj+dqpuut78C+0Hvj6srUOeGZKveZ6wb+Oa7qygHnoWwFIMahimuaVo2lBb7Cs6rrup63qflQgYhreYYRtmEqxlhK6Zhxyb4q+p7CjxAhZgJ2z-nh+ZEYR-CyJU3RIFeWy7JA87HL0-jjosU4IrO6mHJpdRFLeEE-qCc6IkgADkiqbDZqHEFU1FqpBRAwECiBPD87xUK5TlENQxxUAAKhAAAe1lSm5y7cCU5lPpZhnsDZlBRSAVB6o5onHPWUAtshVCBUgnn0D52x+QFonBea4VRdVskJTVan7KlTGOVRtkdbe8WRIly7JW1tnwE8EDwB4XwRZ1LkjWNE1TTZvXNUR-BDRQqVQJZ8DkJ1UDVtA7AVgdUDBr1HJtAp+CdtAcAiG4VAMMAGDkGNzFnCkUyjvVqlWQuvQDUFrUbbZ9m7ees0xeeZXeb51CNUlVAhT9CPEHJw4WCIP0MFlIAGfs-2nLe63WWlkXkJl2XnnlBVIX6xW3jDEAVVVwmxfGtVheTqNEOjvEjsoAByRX4xpi6A0gJPtUVOVEbNNkdQaoYlsoKjzZNGARaLRni8TwOk6N40a9NEMCnNRuLUrn0qyI5bbb9hmE0ug365t9uy0++01rTx3e8GVv4Ip2QqdrTvafMukh-rTumURP2h8Z0S3tjuMJ4u4S3sL9Np70GdEWrFuazndR50+du7DtxcXeM3BAA)

Answer (score 0):

This was what I ended up doing

```
  interface GenericInputElementProps {
  id: string;
  hidden: boolean;
  label: string;
  onInput: (
    id: string,
    value: string | number,
    isValid: boolean
  ) => {
    type: string;
    value: string | number;
    inputId: string;
    isValid: boolean;
  };
  validators?: { type: string; configVal?: number }[];
  initialValue?: {
    initialValue: string;
    initialValid: boolean;
  };
}
type TextElementProps = GenericInputElementProps & {
  element: 'input';
  type: string;
  placeholder: string;
  errorText: string;
};
type TextAreaElementProps = GenericInputElementProps & {
  element: 'textarea';
  rows: number;
  placeholder: string;
  errorText: string;
};
type NumberElementProps = GenericInputElementProps & {
  element: 'number';
  type: 'number';
};
type CheckboxElementProps = GenericInputElementProps & {
  element: 'checkbox';
  type: 'checkbox';
};
type SelectElementProps = GenericInputElementProps & {
  element: 'select';
  sizes: ISizes[];
};
```

Then

```
 export const Input = (
  props:
    | TextElementProps
    | TextAreaElementProps
    | NumberElementProps
    | CheckboxElementProps
    | SelectElementProps
) => {};
```

Perhaps it looks a bit ridiculous but it worked splendidly.

Comment: The suggestion in the comments was to do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQxzYW); you say "it didn't seem to work", but *how*?  This type and the one in your answer are essentially identical (except I don't know what `ISizes` is).

Comment: Instead of typing everything and then putting it in parenthesis, I just used the brackets alone, and it wasn't working, but to be fair, it was messy and prettier wasn't helping. What you did looks clean. ISizes is an array of objects with id value and isValid, but I don't see what that's important. The question was purely about the logic, which you were able to provide. If you post it as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: If `ISizes` doesn't matter then having it in the question is at best a distraction, since it wasn't defined and caused an unrelated IDE error; the point of a [mre] is to focus on the issue without adding extraneous things that pull attention away from it. But anyway as long as my random definition of `ISizes` doesn't change anything about your issue then I'll leave it as-is.  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.